# Clear pex turning brittle

Tags: plumbing

About 5 years ago we had a bathroon remodel and the contractor used clear pex for the hot water service. Last week we realized that we had a leak under the tile. Today a different plumber dug down and as he got to the pex he tried to lift it a bit and it just snapped and broke in his hand. The tubing that is there is so brittle that it has cracks in the wall of the tubing. Are there other instances of this happening? If so what remediation has been done to correct it?

Comment: Was the clear pex only rated to 50 deg C and it has been used above that temperature for example?

Comment: We are working with the original contractor to make sure of the manufacturer and product warrenty. I know we will need to replace all the hot water service in the remodeled area. I'm trying to figure out the least impactful routing, and who will be paying for it.